# MongoDB list databases with given prefix in Go

Tags: mongodb, go, mongo-go

## Question

How can I list databases only with the given prefix (`prefix_`)?

## Example:

```golang
package main

import (
  "context"
  "fmt"
  "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
  "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
  "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
  "log"
)

type foo struct {
  Value string
}

func main() {
  clientOptions := options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://10.0.12.76:27018")
  client, err := mongo.Connect(context.TODO(), clientOptions)
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }
  db := [3]string{"prefix_foo", "prefix_bar", "bar"}

  for _, element := range db {
    _, err := client.Database(element).Collection("placeholder").InsertOne(context.TODO(), foo{"sth"})
    if err != nil {
      log.Fatal(err)
    }
  }

  filter := bson.D{{}}

  dbs, err := client.ListDatabaseNames(context.TODO(), filter)
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }
  fmt.Printf("%+v\n", dbs)
}
```

## Output:

`[admin bar config local prefix_bar prefix_foo]`

## Expected output:

`[prefix_bar prefix_foo]`

## Bonus:

1. It is possible to create a database without defining new `struct` in my case `foo`?
2. My goal is to run a query on databases only with a prefix, so maybe better solution exists than listing dbs and then run a query on each database?

Comment: Try `bson.D{{"name", primitive.Regex{Pattern: "^"+prefix +"*", Options: "i"}}}`, or `bson.D{{"name", bson.D{{"$regex", "^"+prefix+"*"}, {"$options", "i"}}}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply filter by the `name` property, which denotes the database name. And to list databases starting with a given prefix, you may use a regexp being `^prefix_`:

```
filter := bson.M{"name": primitive.Regex{Pattern: "^prefix_"}}
```

Other filter options are listed on the [`listDatabases` command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/listDatabases/) page:

> You can specify a condition on any of the fields in the output of `listDatabases`:
>
> - `name`
> - `sizeOnDisk`
> - `empty`
> - `shards`

And you may use an empty `bson.M{}` to insert an empty document (`_id` will be added of course).

Comment: Thank you, I am pretty sure that I tried sth similar. Anyway, how can I list all property to use it for search?